# Incrementing value with a ForEach loop to apply on each element

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, increment

looking for help with arrays and increments.

I have a function which applies the same style to each new element in an array as you can see below.

```
function SnakeBodyLeft(){
  StorePositions.forEach(BodySnake => {
    BodySnake.style.gridRowStart = (Initial_y + y);
    BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+1 ;
  });
};

// this results in

StorePositions[0] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+1 
StorePositions[1] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+1
StorePositions[2] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+1

And so on...
```

I want to write  a function that does what is shown above , but increments the value +1 for Each new element and keep the initial value for the first elements. The result would be somethink like :

```
StorePositions[0] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+1 
StorePositions[1] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+2
StorePositions[2] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+3
StorePositions[3] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+4

And so on....
```

I have tried to make 1 a variable called i and increment it. But when I do this , the increment of i is applied to all elements in the array and not just the new elements.

```
let i = 1++;

function SnakeBodyLeft(){
  StorePositions.forEach(BodySnake=> {
    BodySnake.style.gridRowStart = (Initial_y + y);
    BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x) + i ;
  });
};


//this results in the incremented value being applied to all elements , not just the new ones .

StorePositions[0] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+1 
StorePositions[1] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+1
StorePositions[2] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+1

or

StorePositions[0] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+2 
StorePositions[1] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+2
StorePositions[2] = BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x)+2
```

Basically , as the index grows(0,1,2,3...) , so should the value i in each new element in the index.(0,1,2,3...).

But Iam kinda stuck ! Anyone can help ?

Comment: try doing `let i = 1;` and then inside your foreach loop, add one more line to the bottom: `i++;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function SnakeBodyLeft(){
  StorePositions.forEach((BodySnake, i)=> {
    BodySnake.style.gridRowStart = (Initial_y + y);
    BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x) + i;
  });
};
```

**UPDATE**
If you need to start the increment from 1 then do this instead:

```
function SnakeBodyLeft(){
  StorePositions.forEach((BodySnake, i)=> {
    BodySnake.style.gridRowStart = (Initial_y + y);
    BodySnake.style.gridColumnStart = (Initial_x + x) + (i + 1);
  });
};
```

You can add an index for the forEach like so `forEach(element, index) => { ... }`

Comment: That works !! 

Now I just need to understand how =D . I assume by puting the I as an argument in the ForEach loop he increments that i??

Comment: Nice one! Check the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)